# Seeking an English version of Minchat Chinuch

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, english, acharonim

Is there an English version of Minchat Chinuch by "Rabbeinu Yosef" (Yosef Ben Moshe Babad, 1800–1874), a commentary on the Sefer ha-Chinuch?